# Replace NA by value of another variable

Tags: r, dplyr

Say this is my data.

```
mydat=structure(list(ItemRelation = c(158200L, 158204L), DocumentNum = c(1715L, 
1715L), CalendarYear = c(2018L, 2018L), X1 = c(0L, 0L), X2 = c(0L, 
0L), X3 = c(0L, 0L), X4 = c(NA, NA), X5 = c(107L, 105L), X6 = c(NA, 
NA)), .Names = c("ItemRelation", "DocumentNum", "CalendarYear", 
"X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

How can I create the condition that if `X6=NA`, then replace `NA` by value of `X5`?

In this example, the desired output would be:

```
  ItemRelation DocumentNum CalendarYear X1 X2 X3 X4  X5  X6
1       158200        1715         2018  0  0  0 NA 107 107
2       158204        1715         2018  0  0  0 NA 105 105
```

Comment: `with(mydat, ifelse(is.na(X6), X5, X6))`

Comment: try `ifelse` like `ifelse(is.na(X6), X5, X6)`

Comment: @RonakShah Looks like an answer to me. If you post as comment instead of answer, it cannot be upvoted or downvoted, or accepted, no one looking at the question queue will see that an answer has been posted (and possibly accepted), etc....

Comment: @RonakShah, your duplicated post did not help for me. But theforestecologist 's solution great works

Comment: @D.Joe can you tell me how it does not help you? `mydat$X6[is.na(mydat$X6)] <- mydat$X5[is.na(mydat$X6)]` works for the given example from the duplicated post. Are you looking something else?

Comment: @duckmayr Thanks, the reason I did not post it as an answer because this question seemed like a duplicate and I was finding one. :)

Comment: @RonakShah Fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` in base R:

```
mydat[,c("X5","X6")] <- with(mydat, sapply(mydat[8:9],function(x) ifelse(is.na(X6),X5,X6)))
```

Giving the desired solution:

```
  ItemRelation DocumentNum CalendarYear X1 X2 X3 X4  X5  X6
1       158200        1715         2018  0  0  0 NA 107 107
2       158204        1715         2018  0  0  0 NA 105 105
```

Explanation:

`ifelse` examines whether the `X6` value for a given row is `NA`, and if so, selects the value of `X5` from that row. If `X6` is *not* NA, then just `X6` is used.

`sapply` allows you to quickly apply this `ifelse` function to every row of your data.frame.

`with` changes the environment so that you're "within" your `mydat` object so that you can refer to its parts without using `$` or `[]`.

Comment: How can this be a correct answer if the contents of `X5` is copied over all other columns? Even `ItemRelation` and `DocumentNum` have been overwritten.

Comment: Your edit makes it worse. Column `X6` is now replaced by **two** columns `X6.X5` and `X6.X6`. This is caused by the unnecessary call to `sapply()`. IMHO, the correct base R solution would be `mydat$X6 <- with(mydat, ifelse(is.na(X6),X5,X6))` but this has already been proposed by  [Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52097756/replace-na-by-value-of-another-variable/52098059#comment91145798_52097756).

Comment: @Uwe, I noticed that I totally misread things the first time, which is why I initially incorporated the `sapply`. I stuck with it since that's the approach that was "accepted" by the OP,  but  then I realized I also made a typo in my edits. It's now fixed. I agree that Ronak's answer is better. If he does not add it as an answer, I can incorporate it into mine.